# How to properly split this piece of text into a series of sentences?

Tags: javascript, split

I need to split a piece of text into sentences. Below is an example.

> The court in Beijing said that the tycoon, Ren Zhiqiang, had used his former posts to take bribes and embezzle public funds, and accused him of illegally enriching himself by about $2.9 million. But Mr. Ren’s supporters are sure to see the long sentence as punishment for his cutting comments about Mr. Xi — and as a warning to other potential critics of Mr. Xi’s rule. The U.S. Government would welcome the prompt response of the DRV to this suggestion. In 2016, the Communist Party had already warned Mr. Ren and put him on probation after he publicly scoffed at Mr. Xi’s comments that Chinese news outlets must serve the party. “When did the people’s government turn into the party’s government?” Mr. Ren wrote.

The following cases need to be considered:

- Mr.
- Mrs.
- Dr.
- U.S.
- $2.9

The expected result is the following series of sentences:

- The court in Beijing said that the tycoon, Ren Zhiqiang, had used his former posts to take bribes and embezzle public funds, and accused him of illegally enriching himself by about $2.9 million.
- But Mr. Ren’s supporters are sure to see the long sentence as punishment for his cutting comments about Mr. Xi — and as a warning to other potential critics of Mr. Xi’s rule.
- The U.S. Government would welcome the prompt response of the DRV to this suggestion.
- In 2016, the Communist Party had already warned Mr. Ren and put him on probation after he publicly scoffed at Mr. Xi’s comments that Chinese news outlets must serve the party.
- “When did the people’s government turn into the party’s government?”
- Mr. Ren wrote.

Can this splitting be implemented in a single regular expression in JavaScript? I can't make it work. Right now I have the following regex as a starting point:

```
[^.!?;:。！？]+?(?!Mr|Mrs|\$\d+\.)[.!?;:。！？]
```

Comment: Don't you mean "The, But, In, When, Mr" as the cases?

Comment: I mean you should not end a sentence at "Mr.", "Mrs." etc.

Comment: Haha, no, not homework. I'm writing a Chrome extension and I need this feature. My current implementation doesn't work very well. If this splitting can't be implemented in a single regex, I may write a piece of code to do it.

Comment: [see why it is broken](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5B%5E.!%3F%3B%3A%E3%80%82%EF%BC%81%EF%BC%9F%5D%2B%3F%28%3F!Mr%7CMrs%7C%5C%24%5Cd%2B%5C.%29%5B.!%3F%3B%3A%E3%80%82%EF%BC%81%EF%BC%9F%5D%2F)

Comment: Couldn't you split the string into words, examine each word one by one?  If it ends it a dot, check if it's a known abbreviation - if it is, it's part of the sentence, it it isn't, it's the end of a sentence.  Build up an array for each sentence and then join the words back together again and start on the next sentence.

Comment: It's not that simple, acronyms at the end of a sentence may be indistinguishable. Consider "Donald Trump became the President of the U.S. The election took place in 2016." vs "Donald Trump became the President of the U.S. after 2016 election campaign". Also there are far far more acronyms to cover, e.g. "Apple, Inc."

Comment: But how would a regexp know that?  You could possibly check the first character of the next word - if it starts with a capital letter, it MAY be a new sentence.  But, even that would not account for "...in the U.S. President Trump...".  I don't think that there is a clear-cut answer.  I have done some code that will create separate sentences out of the string assuming that Mr., Mrs. and U.S. are not the last words in a sentence.  The only difference I have from the requirement is that "Mr. Ren wrote" is deemed to be part of the previous sentence - which, actually, would make sense to me

Comment: It will still probably fall apart on _Samuel L. Jackson_ :)

Comment: This is why we tend to use "open punctuation" nowadays - no dots except at the actual end of sentences.  Much easier ;)

Comment: I can't see any way to be 100% accurate.  The obvious solution, of course, would be to have the source text structured better, so that it is easy to see where the end of a sentence is.  But, I guess that's not going to happen.  There is no sure way to know if anything with a dot ends a sentence or not - even single letter abbreviations could end a sentence or be part of a name, for example.  I think this is one where it has to be best-efforts rather than 100%?

Comment: What is the logic to separate the line between double quotes? `“When did the people’s government turn into the party’s government?” ` It is the type of quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, and also certainly not perfect, is to match what you don't want to change, and capture in a group what you want to keep so you can append a newline after it.

You can extend the first alternation with patterns that you don't want to alter in the text.

In the replacement, you can check if group 1 exists. If it does, use it in the replacement and append a newline. If it does not exists, return the match.

**Explanation**

```
\b(?:Mrs?|Dr)\.|\bU\.S\.|\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: million)?\b|“[^“”]+”|([.!?;:。！？])\s*(?!$)
```

- `\b(?:Mrs?|Dr)\.` Match `Mr.` `Mrs.` or `Dr.`
- `|` Or
- `\bU\.S\.` Match `U.S.`
- `|` Or
- `\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: million)?)` Match a dollar sign, 1+ digits with optional decimal part and optional space and million
- `|` Or
- `“[^“”]+”` Match from opening `“` till closing `”` to prevent breaking inside on a question mark for example
- `|` Or
- `([.!?;:。！？]\s*)` Capture **group 1**, match one of the listed characters in the character class
- `(?!$)` Negative lookahead, assert not the end of string to prevent replacing with an extra newline at the end

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CTjGyH/1)

For example

```js
let pattern = /\b(?:Mrs?|Dr)\.|\bU\.S\.|\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: million)?\b|“[^“”]+”|([.!?;:。！？])\s*(?!$)/g;
let s = `The court in Beijing said that the tycoon, Ren Zhiqiang, had used his former posts to take bribes and embezzle public funds, and accused him of illegally enriching himself by about $2.9 million. But Mr. Ren’s supporters are sure to see the long sentence as punishment for his cutting comments about Mr. Xi — and as a warning to other potential critics of Mr. Xi’s rule. The U.S. Government would welcome the prompt response of the DRV to this suggestion. In 2016, the Communist Party had already warned Mr. Ren and put him on probation after he publicly scoffed at Mr. Xi’s comments that Chinese news outlets must serve the party. “When did the people’s government turn into the party’s government?” Mr. Ren wrote.`;
s = s.replace(pattern, (m, g1) => undefined !== g1 ? g1 + "\n\n" : m);
console.log(s);
```

An example to extend it:

```
\b(?:Mrs?|Dr)\.|\bU\.S\.|\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: million)?\b|“[^“”]+”|(?: |^)[A-Z]\.(?!\S)|([.!?;:。！？])\s*(?!$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/URSIry/1)

Answer (score 1):

This, I think, is the best we could come up with - not perfect, for reasons already discussed, but maybe a starting point?

```js
    let s = "The court in Beijing said that the tycoon, Ren Zhiqiang, had used his former posts to take bribes and embezzle public funds, and accused him of illegally enriching himself by about $2.9 million. But Mr. Ren’s supporters are sure to see the long sentence as punishment for his cutting comments about Mr. Xi — and as a warning to other potential critics of Mr. Xi’s rule. The U.S. Government would welcome the prompt response of the DRV to this suggestion. In 2016, the Communist Party had already warned Mr. Ren and put him on probation after he publicly scoffed at Mr. Xi’s comments that Chinese news outlets must serve the party. “When did the people’s government turn into the party’s government?” Mr. Ren wrote.";

    // Array of known abbreviations or other dot-ended text that ***probably*** isn't the end of a sentence
    const ok = ["Mr.", "Mrs.", "Dr.", "U.S.", "Inc."];

    function findSentences() {
      // split the entire string into words - separated by a space
      let words = s.split(" ");
      // an array to hold all of the sentences the code constructs
      let sentences = [];
      // start with a blank sentence array
      let newsentence = [];
      words.forEach(function(w) {
        // the word does NOT end with a dot, just add it to the sentence
        if (!w.endsWith(".")) {
          newsentence.push(w);
        // if it does, but it's an known abbreviation, just add it as normal
        // Also allow for single letter abbreviations - eg, in "Samuel L. Jackson"
        } else if (ok.find(x => x == w) || w.length == 2) {
          newsentence.push(w);
        // if it does, but it's NOT an known abbreviation, finish the sentence and start a new one
        } else {
          newsentence.push(w);
          sentences.push(newsentence.join(" "));
          newsentence.length = 0;
        }
      })
      // Output the sentences
      let ul = document.createElement("ul");
      sentences.forEach(function(s) {
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = s;
        ul.appendChild(li);
      })
      document.body.appendChild(ul);
    }

    findSentences();
```